# How to mount a windows folder in Linux

Tags: windows, mount

I'm running Linux ( Ubuntu 11.10 ) and Windows ( 7 ) on the same system on two partitions.

So I have this folder in Windows:

```
C:\Users\Me\Folder
```

And I created this folder in Linux:

```
/mnt/Folder
```

Now trying to do something like this:

```
sudo mount /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder /mnt/Folder
```

This doesn't work.  I'm guessing it has to do with that one can only mount a media and not folders.  Anyhow.  Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Try this:http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/05/how-to-mount-a-windows-partition-on-linux-automatically-on-each-start-up/

abd in the fstab..specify the folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `C:` Windows drive is already mounted under `/media/ACER`, you can create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the subdirectory you're interested in:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder /mnt/Folder
```

The `-s` option tells `ln` to create a symlink instead of a hard link, and the `-f` option instructs it to replace `/mnt/Folder` if it exists, so you won't have to delete it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can always mount a `drive`(aka `Paritition`, `Filesystem`) into some folder and not one folder in another.

So in this case, you will need to mount your entire `C:` or `D:` to your folder.

In `Linux`, this folders are seen as `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb3` or anything depending upon your drive creation and kinds of devices that you used.

to know more about your partitions, you can execute `fdisk -l`

to know about your already mounted partitions you can do : `df -h` (h for human readable)

One you have identified, which is your correct partition, like is it `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2` you can mount them in this way:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /path/to/your/folder`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shared mount point. The advantage over creating a symbolic link would be if you unmount the windows folder this would not leave you with a broken symbolic link which is a security issue. To create a shared mount you first have to "mark" the mount point you are using as shared:

```
mount --bind /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder
mount --make-shared /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder
```

now bind a duplicate to /mnt like this

```
mount --bind  /media/ACER/Users/Me/Folder /mnt/Folder
```

You can read more about shared mount points in the red hat documentation [you can find it here](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Using_the_mount_Command-Mounting-Bind.html)

This should also work for ubuntu i tested it on my debian machine:

```
root@Alucard:~# mount --bind /media/DATENKORB/ /media/DATENKORB/
root@Alucard:~# mount --make-shared /media/DATENKORB/
root@Alucard:~# mkdir /mnt/DATENKORB
root@Alucard:~# mount --bind /media/DATENKORB/ /mnt/DATENKORB/
root@Alucard:~# cd /mnt/DATENKORB/
root@Alucard:/mnt/DATENKORB# ls
>> DSC_4988.JPG  _MG_6326.geaendert.JPG
root@Alucard:/mnt/DATENKORB# touch test
root@Alucard:/mnt/DATENKORB# cd /media/DATENKORB
root@Alucard:/media/DATENKORB# ls
>> DSC_4988.JPG  _MG_6326.geaendert.JPG  test
```