# Mount Windows partition, but cant see any files or data

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, windows-8

Following a few guides elsewhere on Ask Ubuntu [How do I access my Windows partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148474/how-do-i-access-my-windows-partition) and [How to mount a windows folder in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109856/how-to-mount-a-windows-folder-in-linux), I can get as far a successfully "seeing" what sda* drive I think I need to mount and get it to work... but when I go through the directory structure all I end up with is a "manifests" folder and nothing else.

Here is what I see:

I run this to check where Windows is: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`
I get this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5B40B459-9C6D-495C-AD53-5F5F1CF8C15A

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047    1024000   500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1026048    1640447     614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1640448    1902591     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1902592 1594544128 1592641537 759.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1594546176 1628263024   33716849  16.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1901746176 1902460927     714752   349M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1902460929 1951426560   48965632  23.4G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8  1951426561 1953523712    2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda9  1628264448 1889777663  261513216 124.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1889777664 1901746175   11968512   5.7G Linux swap

Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I pick `/dev/sda4` for this mount command: `sudo mount --source /dev/sda4 --target /media/windows_mount/`

This allows me to cd through the following path an I end up with what I think is an empty directory (`ls` gives me nothing): `/media/windows_mount/Windows/WinSxS/Manifests$`

**So question is**, assuming the mount process worked, why can't I see anything in the Windows folders?

As you can tell with my terminology, I've not done this before. I'm just trying to drag over a load of images that should be on the Windows partition but currently fail to get anywhere. When I try to dual boot back into Windows is also fails, so maybe its corrupt?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I tried the same process with `dev/sda5` but get a similar result.

Comment: Is this for Win 7 or later Windows.  Later Windows use a fast boot option that hibernates instead of shutting down.

Comment: well spotted - it's Windows 8. I've changed the tag

Comment: Would be better to use windows tools to try to fix windows.  If you need a windows install usb to fix, can download windows in ubuntu but also need to download woeusb to make a bootable windows usb.

Comment: Windows also turns fast startup back on with updates, so you may have to regularly redo turning it off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: running `fuser -m /dev/sda4` I get a `/dev/sda4:            5419c` . This was prompted by using one of the commands from one of your links @oldfred to mount as read only, this cmd: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4 /media/windows_mount/` where I get an error of `Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.`